# Jquery's form serialization sends repeated information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, serialization

I send form data using `Jquery's $("form").serialize()` method. I display the serialized data as `alert($("form").serialize());` and found some repeated messages.

What could be the problem there?

The logged message is shown in the attached image.
There are repeated data (underlined). The first one is fine `stories=3&bedrooms=2&bathrooms=2` for `three SELECT elements`. Then there is another repeated message with `bedrooms=Bedrooms&bathroom=Bathrooms`, then my PHP code at server caught the second one and the value is never changed.

```
stories=3&bedrooms=2&bathrooms
```

are `three SELECT elements` and their default options for `bedrooms and bathrooms` are `Bedrooms and Bathrooms`. Because of the repeated data, no matter I change other options at `bedrooms and bathrooms`, the value sent to server is never changed.
What could be the problem and how to solve?
Thanks

[image]

EDIT:

My HTML code is long. I am just beginner for Webapplications, not sure they are in appropriate way, anyway they are as follow. There are two steps validations, one at client side in the function `function validatelanded( event )` and another one at server `function sendtoServer()`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


<style type="text/css">
#header { background-color:green; color:white; text-align:center; padding:5px;}
#background {background: url(register_background.png);}
body {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.star { color: red;} 
.button { background-color: #4CAF50; border: none; color: white; padding: 15px 32px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; font-size: 16px; margin: 4px 2px; cursor: pointer;
}

.button2:hover { box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);}

.overflow { height: 200px; }
select[required] + label {
    color: #999;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;

    /*left: -230px;  the negative of the input width */
}

select[required] + label:after {
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}

input[required] + label {
    color: #999;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
    /*left: -230px;  the negative of the input width */
}

input[required] + label:after {
    content:'*';
    color: red;
}

input[need] + text{
    color: #999;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;

    /*left: -230px;  the negative of the input width */
}




</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
<h1>Please add your landed property to advertise</h1>
</div>

<div id="background">
<form name="advertiseForm"  id="advertiseForm" method="post" >

<br /><br />
<div class="form_box">
   <div class="input_box ">
      <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="Sell" >To sell
      <input type="radio" name="purpose" value="Rent" required="required">To rent
      <label for="purpose">Please select transaction type</label>      
      <div  id="purpose-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000">

      </div>      
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<br /><br />
<div class="form_box">
   <div class="input_box ">
     <input class="type" type="radio" name="type" value="No_building" >No building
     <input class="type" type="radio" name="type" value="With_RC">With RC
     <input class="type" type="radio" name="type" value="With_BrickNorcal" required="required">With BrickNorcal
     <label for="type">Please select building type</label>
     <div  id="type-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>      
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>




<br /><br /><br />
<select name="stories"  id="stories"  required="required"/>  
     <option value="Stories" >Number of stories</option>  
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2">2</option> 
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option> 
     <option value="morethan4">More than 4</option>
<select/>  
<label for="stories">Please select for number of stories</label>
<div  id="stories-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>

<br /><br /><br />
<select name="bedrooms" id="bedrooms" required="required"/>  
     <option value="Bedrooms" >Number of bedrooms</option>  
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2">2</option> 
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option> 
     <option value="5">5</option>
<select/>  
<label for="numbedrooms">Please select for number of bedrooms</label>
<div  id="bedrooms-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>

<br /><br /><br />
<select name="bathrooms" id="bathrooms" required="required"/>  
     <option value="Bathrooms" >Number of Bathrooms</option>  
     <option value="1">1</option> 
     <option value="2">2</option> 
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option> 
     <option value="5">5</option>
<select/>  
<label for="bathrooms">Please select for number of bathrooms</label>
<div  id="bathrooms-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>



<br /><br /><br />
<select name="divs_states" id="divs_states" required="required"/>  
   <optgroup label="Divisions">
      <option value="Division">Please select one of the following divisions</option>
      <option value="jquery">jQuery.js</option>
      <option value="jqueryui">ui.jQuery.js</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="States">
      <option value="State">Please select one of the following states</option>
      <option value="somefile">Some unknown file</option>
      <option value="someotherfile">Some other file with a very long option text</option>
   </optgroup>    
<select/> 
<label for="divs_states">Please select a region</label>
<div  id="divs_states-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>

<br /><br /><br />
<select name="township" id="township" required="required"/>  
     <option value="Township" >Township</option>  
     <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
     <option value="fiat">Fiat</option> 
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>    
<select/>  
<label for="township">Please select a nearest township</label>
<div  id="township-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>

<br /><br /><br />
<div class="form_box">
    <div class="input_box">
        <input maxlength="100" type="price" name="price" id="price" required="required" />
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <div  id="price-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>        
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<br /><br />
<div class="form_box">
    <div class="input_box">
        <input maxlength="100" type="length" name="length" id="length" required="required" />
        <label for="length">Length in feet</label>        
        <input maxlength="100" type="width" name="width" id="width" required="required" />
        <label for="width">Width in feet</label>
        <br />
        <div  id="length-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>
        <div  id="width-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>        
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<br />
<input type="radio" name="havetelephone" value="yes" checked>Yes
<input type="radio" name="havetelephone" value="no" need="need">No
<text for="havetelephone">Landline telephone installed at home?</text>


<br /><br />
<input type="radio" name="haveaircon" value="yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="haveaircon" value="no" required="required">No
<label for="haveaircon">Aircon installed?</label>
<div  id="haveaircon-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>

<br /><br /><br />
<select name="possession" required="required"/>  
     <option value="Possession" >Possession</option>  
     <option value="saab">Saab</option> 
     <option value="fiat">Fiat</option> 
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>    
<select/>  
<label for="possession">Please select a possession type</label>
<div  id="possession-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>

<br /><br /><br />
<input maxlength="100" type="text" name="date" id="date" required="required" />
<label for="date">Please specify an available date for start use</label>
<div  id="date-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>


<br /><br /><br />
<textarea  rows="20" cols="70" name="textarea" id="textarea" placeholder="Please enter additional information here..."></textarea>
<div  id="textarea-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>

<br /><br />
<div style="color:#0000FF">
  <h3>Contact address</h3>
</div>
<br />


<input type="radio" name="agentowner" value="Agent" >Agent
<input type="radio" name="agentowner" value="Owner" required="required">Owner
<label for="agentowner">Please specify</label>
<div  id="agentowner-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>

<br /><br />

<div class="form_box">
    <div class="input_box ">
        <input maxlength="60" type="text" name="name" id="name" required="required" />
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <div  id="name-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>        
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<br /><br />
<div class="form_box">
    <div class="input_box ">
        <input maxlength="60" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" required="required" />
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <div  id="phone-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<br /><br />
<div class="form_box">
    <div class="input_box">
        <input maxlength="64" type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required" />
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <div  id="email-error" class="error-box" style="color:#FF0000"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<br /><br />
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Please key in full address if you are ok..."></textarea>



<!-- Check on the page itself first -->
<br /><br /><br />
<div style="text-align:center">
<input class="button button2" id="submitbutton" type="button" value="Submit" />
</div>

</form>
</div>

</body>
<script> 
    $("#textarea")
     .focus(function() {
    if ($("#textarea").val() == null) return;
    if ($("#textarea").val() == "Please enter additional information here...") 
        $("#textarea").val('');
    })
    .blur(function() {
    if ($("#textarea").val() == null) return;
    if ($("#textarea").val() == '') 
       $("#textarea").val('Please enter additional information here...');
   });

   $("#address")
   .focus(function() {
    if ($("#address").val() == null) return;
    if ($("#address").val() == "Please key in full address if you are ok...") 
        $("#address").val('');
   })
   .blur(function() {
    if ($("#address").val() == null) return;
    if ($("#address").val() == '') 
       $("#address").val('Please key in full address if you are ok...');
   });  
    $(function() {
         $( "#date" ).datepicker();   
    }); 



  function trimAll( str ) {
    return str.replace( /^\s+|\s+$/g, '' );
   }

function sendtoServer() {
     alert($("form").serialize());
     $.ajax({
        url: "advertisementdatavalidationatserver.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: $("form").serialize(), 
        success:  function(ret){
            alert(ret);
            if(ret.error == true){ 
              if(ret.message.indexOf("Purposeerror")>=0){
                  $('#purpose-error').css('display', 'block');
                  $('#purpose-error').html('Please enter to rent or to sell');
              }else{
                  $('#purpose-error').html(''); 
              } 

              if(ret.message.indexOf("Typeerror")>=0){
                  $('#type-error').css('display', 'block');
                  $('#type-error').html('Please enter your building type');
              }else{
                  $('#type-error').html(''); 
              } 

              if(ret.message.indexOf("Storieserror")>=0){
                  $('#stories-error').css('display', 'block');
                  $('#stories-error').html('Please enter number of stories at your building');
              }else{
                  $('#stories-error').html(''); 
              }

              if(ret.message.indexOf("Bedroomserror")>=0){
                  $('#bedrooms-error').css('display', 'block');
                  $('#bedrooms-error').html('Please enter number of bedrooms at your building');
              }else{
                  $('#bedrooms-error').html(''); 
              }

              if(ret.message.indexOf("Bathroomserror")>=0){
                  $('#bathrooms-error').css('display', 'block');
                  $('#bathrooms-error').html('Please enter number of bathrooms at your building');
              }else{
                  $('#bathrooms-error').html(''); 
              }

              if(ret.message.indexOf("Divisionerror")>=0){
                  $('#divs_states-error').css('display', 'block');
                  $('#divs_states-error').html('Please select a Division or a State');
              }else{
                  $('#divs_states-error').html(''); 
              }

              if(ret.message.indexOf("Townshiperror")>=0){
                  $('#township-error').css('display', 'block');
                  $('#township-error').html('Please select a Township');
              }else{
                  $('#township-error').html(''); 
              }

              if(ret.message.indexOf("Priceerror")>=0){
                  $('#price-error').css('display', 'block');
                  $('#price-error').html('Please include the price');
              }else{
                  $('#price-error').html(''); 
              }

              if(ret.message.indexOf("Priceinvalid")>=0){
                  $('#price-error').css('display', 'block');
                  $('#price-error').html('Price accepts only neumerical digits');
              }else{
                  $('#price-error').html(''); 
              }

           }else{
              $('#purpose-error').html(''); 
              $('#type-error').html(''); 
              $('#stories-error').html(''); 
              $('#bedrooms-error').html('');
              $('#bathrooms-error').html('');
              $('#divs_states-error').html(''); 
              $('#township-error').html(''); 
              $('#price-error').html(''); 
           }
        },
        error: function(){
           // the AJAX request failed as in timed out / bad url etc.

        } 
   });
}


  $( "#submitbutton" ).on( "click", validatelanded );
     function validatelanded( event ){

        if (!$("input[name='purpose']:checked").val()) {  
            $('#purpose-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#purpose-error').html('Please select to Sell or to Rent');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#purpose-error').html('');
        }

        if (!$("input[name='type']:checked").val()) {
            $('#type-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#type-error').html('Please select one of the Building types');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#type-error').html('');
        }

        if($("input[name='type']:checked").val() == "With_RC" || $("input[name='type']:checked").val() == "With_BrickNorcal"){
            if($( "#stories" ).val() == "Stories"){
                 $('#stories-error').css('display', 'block');
                 $('#stories-error').html('Please select number of stories at the building');
                 return false;
            }else{
                 $('#stories-error').html('');
            }

            if($( "#bedrooms" ).val() == "Bedrooms"){
                $('#bedrooms-error').css('display', 'block');
                $('#bedrooms-error').html('Please select number of bedrooms at the building');
                return false;
            }else{
                $('#bedrooms-error').html('');
            }

            if($( "#bathrooms" ).val() == "Bathrooms"){
                $('#bathrooms-error').css('display', 'block');
                $('#bathrooms-error').html('Please select number of bathrooms at the building');
                return false;
            }else{
                $('#bathrooms-error').html('');
            }
        }

        if($( "#divs_states" ).val() == "Division" || $( "#divs_states" ).val() == "State"){
            $('#divs_states-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#divs_states-error').html('Please select a Division or a State');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#divs_states-error').html('');
        }

        if($( "#township" ).val() == "Township" ){
            $('#township-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#township-error').html('Please select a township');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#township-error').html('');
        }

        var price = $('#price').val();
        if ($.trim(price) == '' ) {
            $('#price-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#price-error').html('Please include price');
            return false; 
        }else if(!price.match(/^\d+$/)){
             $('#price-error').css('display', 'block');
             $('#price-error').html('Price can include only numerical digits');
             return false;
        }else{
            $('#price-error').html('');
        }  

        var length = $('#length').val();
        if ($.trim(length) == '' ) {
             $('#length-error').css('display', 'block');
             $('#length-error').html('Please include length of the land');
             return false; 
        }else if(!length.match(/^\d+$/)){
             $('#length-error').css('display', 'block');
             $('#length-error').html('Please include length in correct format');
             return false;         
        }else{
            $('#length-error').html('');
        } 

        var width = $('#width').val();
        if ($.trim(width) == '' ) {
             $('#width-error').css('display', 'block');
             $('#width-error').html('Please include width of the land');
             return false; 
        }else if(!width.match(/^\d+$/)){
             $('#width-error').css('display', 'block');
             $('#width-error').html('Please include width in correct format');
             return false;        
        }else{
            $('#width-error').html('');
        } 

        if (!$("input[name='haveaircon']:checked").val()) {
            $('#haveaircon-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#haveaircon-error').html('Please select for the aircon');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#haveaircon-error').html('');
        } 

        if($( "#possession" ).val() == "Possession"){
           $('#possession-error').css('display', 'block');
           $('#possession-error').html('Please select possession type');
           return false;            
        }else{
            $('#possession-error').html('');
        } 

        if ($.trim($('#date').val()) == '' ) {
             $('#date-error').css('display', 'block');
             $('#date-error').html('Please include available date for start use');
             return false; 
        }else{
            $('#date-error').html('');
        } 


        if ($('#textarea').val() == "" || $('#textarea').val() =="Please enter additional information here...")
        {
             $('#textarea-error').css('display', 'block');
             $('#textarea-error').html('Please enter additional information in the above text area...');
             return false; 
        }else{
            $('#textarea-error').html('');
        } 


        if (!$("input[name='agentowner']:checked").val()) {
            $('#agentowner-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#agentowner-error').html('Please select Agent or Owner');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#agentowner-error').html('');
        }

        var name = $('#name').val();
        if( $.trim(name) == '' ){
            $('#name-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#name-error').html('Please include name of the person who submit this advertisement.');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#name-error').html('');
        }

        var phone= $('#phone').val();
        if ($.trim(phone) == '') {
            $('#phone-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#phone-error').html('Please include phone number to contact.');
            return false;
        } else if(phone.length < 6){
            $('#phone-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#phone-error').html('Please include valid phone number to contact.');
            return false;
        }else if (!phone.match(/^[0-9]+$/)){
            $('#phone-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#phone-error').html('Please include valid phone number to contact.');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#phone-error').html('');
        }

        var email= $('#email').val();          
        if ($.trim(email) == '') {
            $('#email-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#email-error').html('Please include email number to contact.');
            return false;
        }else if (!email.match(/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i)) {
            $('#email-error').css('display', 'block');
            $('#email-error').html('Please include valid email number to contact.');
            return false;
        }else{
            $('#email-error').html('');
        } 


        sendtoServer();
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Maybe there are several forms on your document...? if so, use an `id` attribute and update your jquery selector for that specific form.
2. Share the form's code.

Comment: Can you show the code of your document html?

Comment: are you use `each` function on javascript

Comment: share the html / form, its probably your problem, and share the entire form, or reproduce it in something like jsfiddle and link to that

Comment: @OfirBaruch thanks I have shared the code in EDIT.

Comment: @Sapikelio, thanks I have shared the code in EDIT.

Comment: Amm.. that's weird. I don't see any mention of "floor" in the form while the serialized output contains it. Are you sure that this is the updated code you're using?

Comment: @OfirBaruch, that is the latest code. Yes I also noticed that floor, but dont have in my code. That is the whole code I use.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Thanks now I know where the problem is. I have three taps. One tap for one category. This form is used for one tap. I have another tap with another form. Now the problem is when I submit the form, both form elements from  these two different taps are serialized and sent to server together. If I have two forms at two different tap, how should I serialized and send to server. I use $(#form).serialize(), both forms are serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I work with multiple forms I give each opening `<form>` tag a unique id and serialize data on that specific id. Your form in your edit has the 'advertiseForm' id, not 'form'. Don't forget the `#` character when writing ids in js.

Your js should look like this: `$("#advertiseForm").serialize()`, this will serialize the form with the id 'advertiseForm'. The other form must also have a unique id or class name in order to serialize it properly.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.